# OpenCV Stereo Calibration: Getting y-offset in rectified images despite using pixel-perfect synthetic keypoint matches

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I'm trying to learn about stereo calibration using synthetic data rendered in Blender. My scene setup looks as follows:

[image: Synthetic stereo rig setup]

This allows me to extract pixel-perfect keypoint correspondences. I'm simulating a gradual (but extreme) decalibration of the cameras, i.e. the cameras rotate out of an initially perfectly front-parallel configuration (**[see video](https://imgur.com/GGSqprK)**).

[image: Synthetic Keypoints]

However, if I try to rectify my images with these perfect keypoint correspondences using OpenCV, I get rectified images that, invididually are *straight,* i.e. the horizon line looks horizontal, but the epipolar lines between the images are not horizontal, i.e. the lines connecting the projections of the same scene point in both images are not horizontal.

[image: Original vs. Rectified Images]

I am assuming known camera intrinsics but unknown extrinsics, i.e. the extrinsics are derived from the (pixel-perfect) keypoint correspondences.

My code looks as follows:

```py
DATA_DIR = "../data/street_sunset_motionblur"
FRAME = 149

# Load images
left_rgb_path  = f"{DATA_DIR}/rgb/left/street_sunset_motionblur_{FRAME:04d}_L.tif"
right_rgb_path = f"{DATA_DIR}/rgb/right/street_sunset_motionblur_{FRAME:04d}_R.tif"
img_left  = cv2.imread(left_rgb_path)
img_right = cv2.imread(right_rgb_path)

# Convert from BGR to RGB
img_left = cv2.cvtColor(img_left, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img_right = cv2.cvtColor(img_right, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Load keypoint correspondences.
# Correspondences array has shape (N, 5) where each row is a keypoint and each
# row has the format [x_left, y_left, x_right, y_right, keypoint_id])
keypoints_path = (f"{DATA_DIR}/keypoints/correspondences_{FRAME}.npy")
correspondences = np.load(keypoints_path)

# Split into left points [x_left, y_left] and right points [x_right, y_right] 
points_left  = correspondences[:, :2]
points_right = correspondences[:, 2:4]

# Load intrinsics matrices
K_left  = np.load(f"{DATA_DIR}/camera_matrices/cam_intrinsic_matrix_{FRAME}_L.npy")
K_right = np.load(f"{DATA_DIR}/camera_matrices/cam_intrinsic_matrix_{FRAME}_R.npy")

# Step 1: Compute the Fundamental Matrix
F, mask = cv2.findFundamentalMat(points_left, points_right, cv2.FM_LMEDS)

# Step 2: Compute the Essential Matrix
E = K_right.T @ F @ K_left

# Step 3: Decompose the Essential Matrix to obtain the rotation and translation
_, R, t, _ = cv2.recoverPose(E, points_left, points_right, K_left)

# Specify image size in (width, height) format
image_size = (img_left.shape[1], img_left.shape[0])

# Step 4: Compute the rectification transforms
R1, R2, P1, P2, _, _, _ = cv2.stereoRectify(
    cameraMatrix1=K_left,
    distCoeffs1=None,
    cameraMatrix2=K_right,
    distCoeffs2=None,
    imageSize=image_size,
    R=R,
    T=t,
    flags=cv2.CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY,
    alpha=-1,
)

# Step 5: Compute the rectification maps
map1_x, map1_y = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(K_left, None, R1, P1, image_size, cv2.CV_32FC1)
map2_x, map2_y = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(K_right, None, R2, P2, image_size, cv2.CV_32FC1)

# Step 6: Apply the rectification maps
rectified_left  = cv2.remap(img_left, map1_x, map1_y, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
rectified_right = cv2.remap(img_right, map2_x, map2_y, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or what I'm missing? Given perfect keypoint matches and intrinsics, shouldn't I be able to get rectified images where a scene point shows up on the same pixel row in both images?

Comment: please show the epipolar lines. -- note that epipolar lines only make sense for two views whose origins don't coincide (i.e. not just rotated). epipolar geometry is a thing in multi-view situations, e.g. with stereo cameras. -- I'm very impressed by that virtual setup you have, specifically the synthetic keypoints and I assume the scriptability. where can I learn more about this?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz The cameras are offset by 0.9m along the world x-axis, as can be seen in the first image. The orange camera frustum (wireframe) shows the left camera, the black camera frustum to its right shows the right camera. The do not share the same optical centre. I created that setup using Blender, which has a useful Python scripting API. Beyond general Blender tutorials I’m not sure what learning resources specific to this use case I could recommend.

Comment: I didn't even notice the black camera wireframe! thanks for considering my side question.